# How can I apply the same settings to each subplot of a plot?

Tags: matlab, plot

The code snippet below applies the large font size only to the bottom plot, not the top plot.

```
subplot(2,1,1)
pcolor(lon(Lon2Use),-dep,v(Lon2Use,:)'); shading('flat'); colorbar
subplot(2,1,2)
pcolor(lon(Lon2Use),-dep,PressureGeo(Lon2Use,:)'); shading('flat'); colorbar
set(gca,'FontSize',20)
title('v along constant latitude line')
xlabel('longitude')
ylabel('depth')
```

How can I do it for the top plot too, preferably with as few extra steps as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple options. Since the function [`gca`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gca.html) always returns the handle of the axis that has the current focus, the easiest solution is simply to repeat the command after making each plot:

```
subplot(2,1,1)
pcolor(lon(Lon2Use),-dep,v(Lon2Use,:)');shading('flat');colorbar
set(gca,'FontSize',20)    %<----First axis has focus at this point
subplot(2,1,2)
pcolor(lon(Lon2Use),-dep,PressureGeo(Lon2Use,:)');shading('flat');colorbar
set(gca,'FontSize',20)    %<----Second axis has focus at this point
```

Alternatively, if you want all your axes to always have that font size by default, you can [set the default size](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/setting-default-property-values.html) on the [root object](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rootobject.html) like so before running any of the above code:

```
set(0, 'DefaultAxesFontSize', 20);
```

And your axes will automatically have that font size.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options here. You could either just repeat the call before you create the second axes, i.e.,

```
subplot(2,1,1)
pcolor(lon(Lon2Use),-dep,v(Lon2Use,:)');shading('flat');colorbar
set(gca,'FontSize',20)
subplot(2,1,2)
pcolor(lon(Lon2Use),-dep,PressureGeo(Lon2Use,:)');shading('flat');colorbar
set(gca,'FontSize',20)
```

OR, you could store the return values from `subplot` (axes handles) and set the properties of these, i.e.,

```
ax = [];

ax = [ax; subplot(2,1,1)];
pcolor(lon(Lon2Use),-dep,v(Lon2Use,:)');shading('flat');colorbar
ax = [ax; subplot(2,1,2)];
pcolor(lon(Lon2Use),-dep,PressureGeo(Lon2Use,:)');shading('flat');colorbar
set(ax,'FontSize',20);
```

I personally favour the latter solution, because the code doesn't change if you change the number of subplots.